# Wordpress: same title but different slugs when site is used in various languages

Tags: wordpress

If i set the WordPress in English (general->site language) and add the the category "München" i get the slug "munchen"

If i set the WordPress in German(Deutsch) and add the same category, "München", i get the slug  "muenchen", which is different than the English version "munchen".

Based on my research i understand that WordPress create slugs considering each language "grammatical rules"

How i can make WordPress(programmatically) create the same slugs(like English version) no matter if Wordpress is using English, Deutsch etc as site language.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using WPML or else?

Comment: no - just simple Wordpress, no translation plugins

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$lang = get_bloginfo('language');

if( $lang === 'es-ES' ){
    //url 
} else {
   // url 
}
return $url;
}
```